# Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ measurable and $f:A \to \Bbb R$. Denote $A_0 =\{x \in A \mid f \text{ cont at $x$} \}$. Show that $f$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ measurable and $f:A \to \Bbb R$. Denote $A_0 =\{x \in A \mid f \text{ continuous at $x$} \}$. Suppose that $m(A \setminus A_0)=0$. Show that $f$ is measurable.

Since $m(A \setminus A_0)=0$ and $A \setminus A_0$ is the set where $f$ is discontinuous we have that $f$ is continuous a.e on $A$. In order for $f$ to be measurable we have to show that for open $U \subset \Bbb R$ the set $f^{-1}[U] = \{x \in A \mid f(x) \in U \}$ is measurable. Now let $U$ be open in $\Bbb R$ we have $$f^{-1}[U] =(f^{-1}[U] \cap (A \setminus A_0)) \cup (f^{-1}[U] \cap A_0).$$

Since $f$ is continuous in $A_0$ the set $(f^{-1}[U] \cap A_0)$ is open in $A_0$ and thus measurable. How can I argue that $f^{-1}[U] =(f^{-1}[U] \cap (A \setminus A_0))$ is measurable? The set $A \setminus A_0$ is measurable but how is the intersection with $f^{-1}[U]$ still measurable since $f$ is not continuous at $A \setminus A_0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here measuarble means Lebesgue measurable, not Borel measurable. Any subset of a set of measure $0$ is Lebesgue measurable and $f^{-1}[U]\cap (A \setminus A_0)$ is a subset of $A \setminus A_0$.

[You should also observe that $A_0=A\setminus (A\setminus A_o)$ is Lebesgue measureble].